# How to set debian 9/10 and putty to show utf-8 chars?

Tags: debian, locale, unicode, putty

> Before opening this question, I google a lot and tried all the suggested fix

### Problem

[pm2 monit](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/#terminal-based-dashboard) util is showed in this way

[image]

instead of

[image]

Strange this: pm2 list is showed right

[image]

### My remote system

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.11 (stretch)
Release:        9.11
Codename:       stretch
```

Putty is installed on a Windows 10 Pro

**Locale config**

```
$ locale
LANG=it_IT.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

### Putty Config

Font used: DejaVu Mono Sans

Window -> Translation settings

[image]

### Question

Simple question is: **how to setup debian system and/or putty to see the right output?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PuTTY ignores the VT100 line-drawing controls when it handles UTF-8.  ncurses can be told that by setting the [**`NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS) environment variable (or using the corrected [`putty`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-putty) terminal description).

Setting [***`TERM`*** to "xterm"](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#xterm_generic) never did work with PuTTY; for a longer answer see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845244/acs-characters-not-working-in-putty-even-with-export-ncurses-no-utf8-acs-1)

Comment: Yet, at the bottom of the "Translation Settings" dialog PuTTY offers `Enable VT100 line drawing even in UTF-8 mode` which fixes the issue right away. Enable it. Restart `pm2 monit`

Comment: I'll update the FAQ when PutTTY defaults `TERM` to **`putty`**.  For the first part, keep in mind that almost all running copies of PuTTY are old enough to apply that advice.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that a top-left corner is substituted by `l`, a horizontal line by `q` and a vertical line by `x` indicates the `pm2_monit` seems to be using the VT100 line drawing characters instead of Unicode line drawing code points.

Since `pm2 list` is shown correctly, I guess it uses the Unicode line drawing code points properly.

Have you tried checking the `Enable VT100 line drawing even in UTF-8 mode` checkbox in PuTTYNG?

Comment: Yes, this option does not change the drawing. Thanks, anyway

Comment: I checked the option and restarted `pm2 monit`. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I added my own answer just to complete my choosen best answer. [https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/544736/167205]

The user said to set `NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS` env variable.

I did using this simple command in my linux console

```
echo export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1 >> ~/.bashrc
```